# Cocos2d-x build error windows eclipse

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am developing an android 2d game using **cocos2d-x**. I have imported a sample project in eclipse but when i tried to build it, it gives me an error:

Build of configuration Default for project HelloCpp **

bash E:/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh -k 
E:/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh: illegal option -- k
NDK_ROOT = E:\zAndroid\android-ndk-r9b
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..
APP_ROOT = /e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
+ 'E:\zAndroid\android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build' -C /e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android -k NDK_MODULE_PATH=/e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..:/e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android'
"C:/program files/git/bin/rm.exe": cannot unlink `NUL': Invalid argument
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: e
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: \zAndroid\cocos2d-x-2.2;e
Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: \zAndroid\cocos2d-x-2.2\cocos2dx\platform\third_party\android\prebuilt
e:/zAndroid/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:68: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/e/zAndroid/cocos2d-x-2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android'

Build Finished **

Comment: Error log is incomplete. You should post detailed log.

Comment: Give proper path to Ndk like this-->  NDK_ROOT="D:\android-ndk-r8d"

Comment: I have the same error, I rename the git directory and it got find the correct rm.exe and works.

Comment: @user1391323 Have you got the solution of this??

Answer (score 2):

Computer --> properties --> Advanced system settings --> Environment Variables.. --> Path( in System variables ) you need remove "C:/program files/git/bin"
Good luck.

Comment: I cant find ...git/bin in my enviroment variables. here is my PATH %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;E:\android-ndk\android-ndk-r9d;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin